# Enum System.Data.SqlDbType

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio

Any idea why I'm getting an error here? I'm trying to do a Parameterized query to insert into database

`Imports System.Data.SqlDbType   --Imported the Correct Library`

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@RichTextBox1 as String", SqlDbType.String)  --Error Here
cmd.Parameters("@RichTextBox1").Value = {RichTextBox1_SuggestionBox.Text}
```

Comment: there is no such thing as `SqlDbType.String`. Use `SqlDbType.VarChar` Also, just use parameter, like `cmd.Parameters.Add("@RichTextBox1"...)`

Comment: Also, the parameter can't be `@RichTextBox1 as String`,change it to just `@RichTextBox`

Comment: Are you using Sql Server or Access? And you should turn on Option Strict or Option Infer. If they were on, you'd have much better error information to tell you the problem.

Comment: Hi Joel... I'm using Sql Server....I'll re run to see what more error info I get

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to

```
cmd.Parameter.Add("@RichTextBox1",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = RichTextBox1_SuggestionBox.Text
```